# One-line ping answer with time and RTD on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, ping, conemu, cmder

How to get the time and response round-trip delay (RTD) of a ping command?

```
ping 10.11.12.13 -n 1
```

every second in the following format:

```
 [time] [delay]
 [time] [delay]
 [time] [delay]
 ...
```

...in a rich Windows command-line application with a Unix command set like Cmder or ConEmu, Cygwin...

Example of output:

```
12:00:01.123  20 ms
12:00:02.432  21 ms
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use the `sed` command. That will still work in case of tiemout.

```
@echo off
:debut

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('ping 10.11.12.13 -n 1 ^| sed -n "3p" ^| sed -r "s/.*time.(.*)\sTTL.*/\1/"' ) DO echo %time%   %%i

sleep 1
goto debut
```

The first `sed` command extract the 3rd line which contains the delay in *ms*.

The second `sed` command extract the delay value, which is after `"time"` in and before `" TTL"`.

NB: you can replace *time* by *temps* for an French version of **ping** on Windows.

Comment: Microsoft Windows does not include a `sed` command. The OP may or may not be permitted to install additional software on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is reasonably easily accomplished by letting PowerShell get the time and format the timestamp.

```
SET "RHOST=www.ibm.com"

powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Test-Connection -ComputerName '%RHOST%' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { '{0}  {1} ms' -f (Get-Date).ToString('HH:MM:ss.fff'), $_.ResponseTime }"
```

Of course, it is easier if the script is just written in PowerShell.

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName 'www.ibm.com' |
    ForEach-Object {
         '{0}  {1} ms' -f (Get-Date).ToString('HH:MM:ss.fff'), $_.ResponseTime
    }
```